# Bootstrap 4 cards - window resize break points

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a quick bootstrap 4 question which I'm sure their is a simple solution for but I'm not a web developer and just trying to get this done.

My Question is:

I'm trying to get a simple 3 card layout to break down to 1 column as the next break point when the window is resized.

For example it skips breaking the 3 cards down to 2 above and 1 below and just goes straight to each card under the other.

Hope that makes sense.
Any advice to how I can achieve this would be appreciated.

Thanks All

Comment: Post the code you have so far. Also are you using a card-deck, card-group or just the cards inside the grid columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use row and cols to achieve that (i.e. col-12 ; col-sm-6 ; col-md-4):

Take the example below as a reference:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h3 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h3>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h3 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h3>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h3 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h3>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h3 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h3>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h3 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h3>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h3 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h3>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to add space below of the cards you can do it like this:

```
.card {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Hope it helped

Comment: Great stuff Serge thanks exactly what I was looking for. I can edit your example code to get the behavior I want. Thank you <3